# Proper way to reload or update getEntityRecords state

Tags: block-editor

I am using a custom document panel component which opens a modal and displays a list of posts and allows the user to make some updates to their terms.

I'm using `getEntityRecords` to load the set of posts. I'm using `editEntityRecord` to make the edits and then `saveEditedEntityRecord` to save the edits.

I would like to update the state with a new call to `getEntityRecords`, but can't figure out the proper way to force a refresh of the second component.

Alternatively, perhaps there is a way to update the state using the entities I get back after `editEntityRecord` rather than trying to re-render the second component?

**Component 1** - Provides the Edit and Save handlers. Component works nicely as does the edit/save process, although I don't know if I'm using these methods as intended

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import CurrentItemList from './current-item-list';
const { useState } = wp.element;
const { Button } = wp.components;
const { withDispatch } = wp.data;
const { compose } = wp.compose;

const CurrentCollectionItems = props => {

    const { postType, editEntityRecord, saveEditedEntityRecord, collection_term } = props;
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

    // Select or deselect the items that will receive the edit
    const onChange = selectedItem => {
        if (selected.includes(selectedItem)) {
            setSelected(_.filter(selected, item => item !== selectedItem))
        } else {
            setSelected([...selected, selectedItem])
        }
    }

    // Edit handler
    const editSelected = () => {

        // Loop over selected items and apply the edit by calling editEntityRecord
        const editedEntities = selected.map(item => {
            return editEntityRecord(
                'postType',
                postType.slug,
                item.id,
                {
                    "artwork_collection_id": _.filter(item.artwork_collection_id, termId => termId !== collection_term.id),
                }
            )
        });

        // When all editing calls are complete pass the edited entities to the save handler
        Promise.all(editedEntities).then(entity => {
            console.log("All Edited. Save entities")
            saveEdited(entity);
        })
    }

    // Save handler
    const saveEdited = (editedEntities) => {

        // Loop the edited entities and call saveEditedEntityRecord
        const results = editedEntities.map(entity => {

            // first remove the item from the selected list
            setSelected(_.filter(selected, si => si.id !== entity.recordId))

            // dispatch to save the entity
            return saveEditedEntityRecord('postType', entity.name, entity.recordId);
        })

        // All entities have been saved
        Promise.all(results).then(response => {

            console.log("All Saved");

            /* TODO: update date with edited entities or trigger another call to getEntityRecords */

        });
    }

    return <div>
        <Button
            isPrimary
            disabled={selected.length ? false : true}
            onClick={editSelected}
        >
            Edit Selected
        </Button>

        <CurrentItemList
            selected={selected}
            onChange={onChange}
        />
    </div>
}

export default compose([
    withDispatch(dispatch => {
        return {
            editEntityRecord: dispatch('core').editEntityRecord,
            saveEditedEntityRecord: dispatch('core').saveEditedEntityRecord,
        }
    })
])(CurrentCollectionItems)
```

**Component 2** - uses withSelect to get entities. I Want to update these entities either in state or re-render this component

```
import ItemListing from './edit-item-listing';
const { withSelect } = wp.data;
const { compose } = wp.compose;

const CurrentItemList = props => {

    const { entities, selected, onChange } = props;
    
    // 
    const items = entities && entities.length ? entities : [];

    // Displays a list of items, each has a checkbox for 
    // and calls onChange when it's selected
    return <div>
        {items.map((item, index) => <ItemListing
            item={item}
            index={index}
            onChange={onChange}
            selected={selected.includes(item)}
        />)}
    </div>
}

export default compose([
    withSelect((select, ownProps) => {
        return {

            /**
             * this property needs to be updated following a save
             */
            entities:  select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', ownProps.collection.meta.artwork_collection_post_type, {
                per_page: 10,
                artwork_collection_id: ownProps.collection_term.id
            })
        }
    })
])(CurrentItemList)
```

Comment: The `useSelect` hook accepts a second dependencies argument - basically the same as the useEffect hook - a state change in a dependency will cause your `getEntityRecords` query to be re-executed. I can't find any documentation on it, but `withSelect` might too.